# Moving transparently between wireless / wired connectivity?

Tags: macos, networking

I'm using Mac OS X. Both at home and work, I like to be able to move around with my laptop. However, when sitting on my desk, I'd like to use the wired network so that big file transfers are faster.

Right now, I've set the wired network to be the default. However, this means that when disconnecting and moving to wireless, I lose my SSH sessions, open network shares etc. since the IP changes.

Likewise, if I'm on wireless and connect my wired network, i need to reconnect my network shares etc in order to get the connections out on the wired network.

What is the simplest solution to this problem? My ideas so far:

- Tunnel all traffic through OpenVPN
- Use same MAC address for both wired and wireless interfaces, make sure only one is connected to the same network at a time (sounds like a dirty solution).

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you could make a virtual network connection that has it's own IP and redirects traffic to the appropriate network interface (wireless or wired), then I guess that would be a third option.